# Is there any difference between de-Broglie wavelength and the wavelength of normal waves?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electromagnetic-radiation

Is de-Broglie wavelength different from wavelength of waves such as electromagnetic waves?

If yes, they differ in what respect?

And can we use the formula of wavelength of light ($c=v\lambda$) to calculate the de-Broglie wavelength?

Comment: de-broglie wavelength is the wavelength associated with a particle with mass. h/p=de-broglie wavelength, where p is momentum, h is planck's constant.

Comment: duplicate of http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33460/why-replace-c-with-v-in-broglie-hypothesis ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is de-Broglie wavelength different from wavelength of waves such as
>   electromagnetic waves?

I would atually say *no*, there is no difference, since the wavelength is purely mathematical characteristic of a wave, the distance over which the wave's shape repeats. There is, however, an important difference between de-Broglie waves on the one side and usual physical waves (mechanical & electromagnetic) on the other:

- The later consist of periodic oscillations of a *physical* quantity, such as, for instance, the pressure for sound waves or electrical and magnetic fields for electromagnetic waves.
- The former consist of periodic oscillations of a *mathematical* quantity, the probability of finding a particle at some location.